# Adding conditional prefixes to column names

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with some weird suffixes, like _a or _b that map to certain codes, I was wondering how would you add a prefix depending on the the suffix and remove the suffix to something easier to understand.

i.e.:

```
    red_a    blue_a    green_b
....
....
```

to

```
    A red    A blue   B green
....
....
```

I tried

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col.endswith('_a'):
        batch_match[col].replace('_a', '')
        batch_match[col].add_prefix('A ')
    else:
        batch_match[col].add_prefix('B ')
```

But it returns a df of NaN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a customer mapper

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"red_a": ['a', 'b', 'c'], "blue_a": [1, 2, 3], 'green_b': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
)

def renamer(col):
    if any(col.endswith(suffix) for suffix in ['_a', '_b']):
        prefix = col[-1]                        # use last char as prefix
        return prefix.upper() + " " + col[:-2]  # add prefix and strip last 2 chars
    else:
        return col

df = df.rename(mapper=renamer, axis='columns')
print(df)
#   A blue B green A red
#0       1       x     a
#1       2       y     b
#2       3       z     c
```

Comment: Would there a more general case where A != 'a'.upper() and not all columns contain the format string_a?

Comment: @RoyHan you can make the `renamer` function as general as you want. It takes in a column name and returns a modified column name.For example, I have edited the function to do nothing if the column doesn't end in `_a` or `_b`. If  you have a more specific requirement, please edit  your question to include the details.

Answer (score 0):

What I will do

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('_').map(lambda x : '{} {}'.format(x[1].upper(),x[0]))
df
Out[512]: 
  A red  A blue B green
0     a       1       x
1     b       2       y
2     c       3       z
```

Comment: Would there be a more general case where A != 'a'.upper() and not all columns contain a string_a format (i.e. columns = ['string1', 'string 2', 'string_a', 'str_ing a'])?